# Regenerate session ids in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller

How can I regenerate session ids in Laravel 5.2 and change session id on every request and deleting old session ids?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: to know whether session hijacking is possible or not. Well copying the sessionids from http headers and working with TamperData in Mozilla i'm able bypass the login.